# Syntaxnet / Parsey McParseface declarative sentences only?

Tags: syntaxnet, parsey-mcparseface, google-cloud-nl

I cannot seem to find detail on the the data parsey was trained on; I am assuming it was mostly, if not all, on declarative sentences. If that's true, then Syntaxnet / parsey might not be the solution for imperative sentences, such as instructional text. Is this accurate? Is there anything out there that works with imperative sentence structure?

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in [official docs](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet#obtaining-data):

> The included English parser, Parsey McParseface, was trained on the
>   the standard corpora of the Penn Treebank and OntoNotes, as well as
>   the English Web Treebank, but these are unfortunately not freely
>   available.

Answer (score 0):

Parsey McParseface is trained on the [Penn Treebank](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/home.html) as well as the [Web Treebank](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/ldc2012t13). The cloud parser has additional proprietary data to help cover some of the gaps.

Parsey actually does pretty well on imperatives, though I don't have actual numbers to back that up -- but if you just try things, it mostly does well in my experience. The cloud system may do a bit better than that as well. In both cases there are imperative examples in our training data.

For example:
[image: imperative parse tree]

This was the first thing I tried. Note that "try" is often a noun, so there's some ambiguity for it to figure out, and it gets it right.